# NSMatrix NSArrayController binding issues --- ugh

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-bindings, key-value-observing, nsarraycontroller, nsmatrix

I want to manipulate an `NSMutableArray` property of an array controller which acts at the content for an `NSMatrix`, without having to manually add the cells to the `NSMatrix` to which it is bound.

I've spent many hours on this, but to no avail.

Any help would be *really* appreciated.

I have a programmatically created an `NSMatrix` in `NSListModeMatrix` mode.  In my `NSArrayController` subclass, I populate an `NSMutableArray` with 4 dummy objects to start with, representing 4 rows and 1 column of data.  I then bind to that matrix the populated `NSMutableArray`:

```
interface:
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *myArray;

implementation (init):
NSMutableDictionary *bindingOptions = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
[bindingOptions setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] forKey:NSInsertsNullPlaceholderBindingOption];
[bindingOptions setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] forKey:NSRaisesForNotApplicableKeysBindingOption];

[matrix bind:@"content"
    toObject:self
 withKeyPath:@"myArray"
     options:bindingOptions];
```

Now I want to add columns to the matrix.  For the first addition, this means a set of cells that are indexed at locations 1,3,5,7 with col=1.  This is due to the left-to-right, top-to-bottom nature of the `NSMatrix` backing content array:

```
NSInteger colCount = [matrix numberOfColumns];
NSInteger rowCount = [matrix numberOfRows];
NSMutableArray *newList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
NSMutableIndexSet *myIndexes = [[NSMutableIndexSet alloc] init];
for (NSInteger i=0; i<rowCount; i++) {
    [newList addObject:[[NSCell alloc] init]];
    [myIndexes addIndex:col+colCount*i];
}
```

Now, here is what I'd like to do:

```
  [self.myArray insertObjects:newList atIndexes:myIndexes];
```

Hoping that the `NSMatrix` will automatically update.  But, alas, no.

I can `NSLog` to confirm that the array is increasing in size (and is correctly laid out), but nothing updates in the UI unless I do the following instead:

```
// update the `NSMatrix` manually
  [matrix insertColumn:col withCells:newList];
// update the underlying array
  [self willChange:NSKeyValueChangeInsertion valuesAtIndexes:myIndexes forKey:@"myArray"];
  [self.myArray insertObjects:newList atIndexes:myIndexes];
  [self didChange:NSKeyValueChangeInsertion valuesAtIndexes:myIndexes forKey:@"myArray"];
```

If I leave out the first line, the `NSMatrix` is entirely blank.

If I leave out the second & last (`willChange`/`didChange`) lines and keep the first line, the matrix only shows the default single column.

In all cases, though, I see the underlying array is growing correctly in size and arrangement.

But I only want to update the underlying mutable array, without having to kludgingly add columns to the `NSMatrix` myself.

**How do I get `NSMatrix` to play along?**

PS: I can shorten the above 4 lines to 2 lines by doing this, ditching the will/did lines:

```
  [matrix insertColumn:col withCells:newList];
  [[self mutableArrayValueForKey:@"myArray"] insertObjects:newList atIndexes:myIndexes];
```